# Can built-in furniture be installed near sprinkler piping?

Tags: code-compliance, fire-sprinkler

I had a loft bed built into my condo.  The bed is up near the ceiling and there is a large red water pipe just above it.  It carries the water to the sprinklers but its not a sprinkler itself.  My bed is about a foot and a half below this pipe.  Is this legal?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @loftbed the first question is legitimate. Different parts of the planets have different laws/rules/local customs.  The second comment was attempting humor.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?  Why is the red pipe a problem for you?

Comment: Did you ask the contractor that built the thing? More importantly, did you ask if you can cover the pipe with foam padding so you don't hit your head on it when you wake up in the middle of the night?

Comment: I don't have a problem with the pipe, I was just wondering what a fire inspector would say about it?  They come in for insurance purposes from time to time and they haven't come into my particular loft.  I never got a permit because the building was still under construction at the time and the contractor said that the current building permit would cover it, however it was never inspected by anyone by the city.  now, several years later, I'm now wondering if it legal being near,(as what you called it) a sand pipe?

Comment: Just don't sit up too swiftly when the fire alarm goes off, you will want to be conscious enough to leave the building. "Dry Standpipe" = air charged water distribution system that fills with water when the firefighting teams need it turned on or hook a tanker up to it.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no sprinkler heads, valves, or such involved -- there's no need to maintain any set clearance from the pipe with nonstructural, non-fire-partitioning elements, such as furniture.  (NFPA 13 has no minimum clearance requirement for sprinkler piping that I can find, save for the 9.3 requirements on clearance through firewalls, and those are both a) driven by seismic concerns and b) on the order of an inch or so.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's legal. **I'm not a lawyer and this is not legal advice**.

I think you're talking about positioning portable furniture (not really *portable*, but you know what I mean).

If the loftbed is permanent construction, you'd have to look a little harder at this. Even in that case, I suspect you'd be fine. Because this sounds to be a dry standpipe for fire fighting.

Comment: _"I had a loft bed built into my condo"_ -- that doesn't sound very portable, sounds like a permanent structure.